# SQL grouping and removing duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

```
tbl_A

ID    data   ID_tbl_B
1     xyz1     15
2     xyz2     15
3     xyz3     15

tbl_B   (table for which file the data were taken, or table for filenames)
ID      ID_user       filename 
15      10            abcd.xls
16      10            abcd2.xls
17      10            abcd3.xls

tbl_C   (table for duplicates from tbl_A)
ID        ID_tbl_B     ID_tbl_A       
4           15          1              
5           15          2
6           15          3
7           16          1
8           16          2
8           16          2
9           17          1
10          17          2
```

`tbl_A` contains the data taken from each file from `tbl_B`. 
E.g, the file (abcd.xls) contains the following data:

```
abcd.xls
xyz1
xyz2
xyz3
xyz1   <--duplicate
xyz2   <--duplicate
xyz3   <--duplicate
```

`tbl_C` contains duplicate data. 
If the data is already present on `tbl_A`, `tbl_C` will record the ID from `tbl_A` (`ID_tbl_A`),
and also records the ID from `tbl_B` (`ID_tbl_B`) from which file it came from.
E.g., from the example above

```
(tbl_C breakdown)
abcd.xls
ID        ID_tbl_B     ID_tbl_A 
4           15          1              
5           15          2
6           15          3

abcd2.xls
ID        ID_tbl_B     ID_tbl_A 
7           16          1
8           16          2
8           16          2

abcd3.xls
ID        ID_tbl_B     ID_tbl_A 
9           17          1
10          17          2
```

an sql query should output the following:

```
tbl_A(data) 

xyz1
xyz2
xyz3
xyz1
xyz2
xyz1
xyz2
```

I've been stuck on this for a day, and so far, here's the query I'm working on with

```
SELECT data FROM `tbl_A`
LEFT JOIN `tbl_B` ON `tbl_A`.ID_tbl_B = `tbl_B`.ID
LEFT JOIN `tbl_C` ON `tbl_C`.
WHERE `tbl_B`.ID_user = 10
```

I can't even finish the query because I can't exactly come up with a solution.. can someone share their idea with me?

Comment: have you tried adding DISTINCT to the select?

Comment: not yet, I'll update my question if I get it right

Comment: So you really want to return one row per row in tbl_C?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your problem, you should try something like this:

`SELECT distict ta.data 
FROM tbl_c tc
    JOIN tbl_B tb ON tc.ID_tbl_B = tb.ID
    JOIN tbl_A ta ON tc.ID_tbl_A = ta.ID
WHERE tb.ID_user = 10`

Though why would you have two records in tbl_c with the same tbl_a and tbl_b ID?  That part makes no sense to me.